# Swift/iOS - Use Strong Password not being saved to keychain

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to implement the autofill feature for iOS. I have followed all the steps from https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill. I have an associated domain, a valid apple app association file, and I have set the text content types correctly. My issue is, when I am prompted to "use strong password" by the native iOS dialog, my username/password never gets saved to the keychain. I have also validated that I have autofill on and my icloud keychain enabled. Ive also followed https://medium.com/developerinsider/ios12-password-autofill-automatic-strong-password-and-security-code-autofill-6e7db8da1810 , but still not seeing the expected behavior. By clicking use strong password, is the username/pw automatically sent to keychain or do I need to manually do something. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have some code so we can see what could have gone wrong?

Comment: hm I can paste code, but id say its straight forward, I actually just got the keychain to save the username/pw.... I do this by removing the email field from the view hierarchy when the password is autofielled. Which the medium article states, but I dont understand why I would need to do that.

Comment: does that seem correct, I need to remove the email/user field from the view hierarchy to save to keychain?

Comment: Which version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: Did you also follow this : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/supporting_associated_domains and add to your website the file required?

Comment: actually watched https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/?time=31 . Turns out the issue is not removing the user/pw/confirmPw from the view hierarchy. So on my "viewWillDisappear" I am removing the fields from the hierarchy.

Comment: Glad that it's fixed. You can write an answer for your question for those who would have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

actually watched developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2018/204/?time=31 . Turns out the issue is not removing the user/pw/confirmPw from the view hierarchy. So on my "viewWillDisappear" I am removing the fields from the hierarchy, this triggers the save to keychain.